# Как правильно организовать передачу данных с фрагмента в activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как правильно организовать передачу данных с фрагмента в Activity? читал ( https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html ) что для этого нужно в классе фрагмента сделать интерфейс а затем его реализовать в Activity затем в фрагменте при вызове в методе оnAttach () на вход которого идет Activity, к которому присоединен фрагмент.  Это Activity нужно привести к типу интерфейса. Но решил попробовать передать данные с класса Fragment в класс Activity через Intnent intent.putExtra() эта схема работает, зачем тогда интерфейс,что он дает?

что интересно onAttach (Activity а) - This method was deprecated in API level 23.Use onAttach(Context) instead

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    ...
   // Container Activity must implement this interface
  public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
      public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);
  }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Методы обратного вызова используются, когда требуется действие в одном классе по событию в другом классе.  Для коммуникаций в приложении используйте библиотеку *EventBus* и не забивайте себе голову